# Как сделать форму с выводом различных опций?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-form

Есть форма код чуть ниже. Вообщем сейчас работает следующим образом. Есть список select и checkbox  при выборе меняется цена. Суть в том что цена зафиксирована. т.е если выбрать Эмалировка 1, остальные значение будут с фиксированной ценой. Как реализовать  данную затею: Если я допустим выберу Эмалировка 1, ниже опции будут с одной ценой и 
  а при выборе Эмалировка 2 другие значение цены.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('select.bath').change(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('#t_'+id).val($(this).val());
 calc();
});

$('input.bort').click(function(){
 var chk = $(this).prop('checked'),
  id = $(this).attr('id');
 $('#t_'+id).val(chk ? $(this).val() : '0руб');
 calc();
});

function calc(){
 var sum = 0;
 $('input.price').each(function(){
  sum += parseInt($(this).val());
 });
 $('#t_summ').val(sum+'руб');
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr style="background:#cfc;"><td>Услуга:</td><td>Цена</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <select id="one" class="bath">
 <option value="0руб">Эмалировка...</option> 
    <option value="350руб">Эмалировка 1</option> 
    <option value="450руб">Эмалировка 2</option> 
    <option value="550руб">Эмалировка 3</option> 
    </select>
</td><td>
 <!-- зависимость с первым selector -->
 <input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_one" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <select id="two" class="bath">
 <option value="0руб">Размер ванны...</option>
    <option value="650руб">Маленькая</option>
    <option value="750руб">Средняя</option>
    <option value="850руб">Большая</option>
    </select>
</td><td>
 <!-- зависимость с вторым selector -->
 <input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_two" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <select id="three" class="bath">
 <option value="0руб">Цвет...</option>
    <option value="950руб">красный</option>
    <option value="1050руб">синий</option>
    <option value="1150руб">зеленый</option>
    </select>
</td><td>
 <!-- зависимость с третьим selector -->
 <input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_three" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
 <input type="checkbox" value="1250руб" id="bath" class="bort"><label for="bath">Установка уголка по бортам ванны</label>
</td><td>
<!-- зависимость с первым radio -->
<input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_bath" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" value="1350руб" id="sink" class="bort"><label for="sink">Установка сливной системы</label>
</td><td>
<!-- зависимость с вторым radio -->
<input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_sink" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" value="1450руб" id="screen" class="bort"><label for="screen">Установка экрана под ванну</label>
</td><td>
<!-- зависимость с третьим radio -->
<input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_screen" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" value="1550руб" id="counter" class="bort"><label for="screen">Установка счетчиков горячей и холодной воды</label>
</td><td>
<!-- зависимость с четвертым radio -->
<input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_counter" class="price">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="checkbox" value="1650руб" id="inspection" class="bort"><label for="inspection">Проверка счетчиков</label>
</td><td>
<!-- зависимость с пятым radio -->
<input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_inspection" class="price">
</td></tr>
 <tr><td>
Итого
</td><td>
 <!-- в этом inpute подсчет стоимости всех выбранных значений -->
<input type="text" value="0руб" id="t_summ">
 </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам бы желательно создать объект типа такого

```
var obj = {
 emal_1 : {
    price_1 : 1000,
    price_2 : 1100,
    price_3 : 1110,
    price_4 : 1111,
 },
 emal_2 : {
    price_1 : 2000,
    price_2 : 2200,
    price_3 : 2220,
    price_4 : 2222,
 },
 emal_3 : {
    price_1 : 3000,
    price_2 : 3300,
    price_3 : 3330,
    price_4 : 3333,
 }
}
```

потом значениям select(который с выбором эмалировок) проставить emal_1, emal_2, emal_3. 
Далее нужно повесить события onChange (на этот - select) при наступлении которого вы будете брать из объекта нужные вам значения. Т.е. выбрали например эмалировка 1 - у этого поля value="emal_1" вот он наш ключик из объекта с ценами